# SignalR-Hub after IIS stop,start will no longer call client functions

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, iis, signalr-hub

I have a queue system using SignalR 2.1.1 with Angular.  Everything is working perfectly actually.  However when I decided to test the system against an IIS outage I noticed a problem.  When I stop, then start IIS, IIS restart doesn't cause the issue, my javascript functions that the hub calls will no longer fire.  That makes sense to me, but the problem is that the client can still call the server without any issue so the user has no idea they are disconnected.  This would certainly mess up my queue state.

So, the solution would seem to be able to test this disconnect somehow and reconnect if necessary. Is there a way to test to see if the client functions my hub is calling are still connected?  It seems that since I can call the hub that it should have to reconnect although I don't see any of that activity happening.  I've tried the disconnected, reconnecting, stateChanged events on the client side to see if I could catch that happening with no luck.

Thank you for any assistance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So my solution was to create a method on the hub that only responds to the caller:

```
    public void LastChange()
    {
        Clients.Caller.lastChange();
    }
```

I hooked that call back to this function in my Angular controller:

```
    vm.queueHub.client.lastChange = function onLastChange()
    {
        vm.lastChangeCalledBack = true;
    }
```

Also in my controller I created this function that tests for the lastChangeCalledBack variable which is set by the function the hub calls.  If it's not set after some interval testing I assume we've lost connection:

```
    vm.stillAlive = function()
    {
        vm.queueHub.server.lastChange();
        var found = $interval(function() 
        {
            if (vm.lastChangeCalledBack == true)
            {
                vm.lastChangeCalledBack = false;
                $interval.cancel(found);
            }
        }, 100, 10);
        return found;
    }
```

Finally I created this function in my controller and call it from any functions that make queue changes from the UI and pass in the callback to call if the connection is still valid. For some reason the promise seems to be reverse of what the Angular documentation says, but I must be misunderstanding: [$interval docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval)

```
    function verifyConnection(callback)
    {
        vm.stillAlive().then(
            function (data) {
                console.log("Lost connection with server: " + data);
                signalrFactory.start();
                var reconnectedMessage = "There was a server disconnect. Your connection has been re-established, but you should reload your browser."
                getQueue(function () { alert(reconnectedMessage); });
            },
            function (data) {
                console.log("Server connection intact: " + data);
                callback();
            }
        );
    }
```

So for example, this is called from the UI to open a modal:

```
    vm.open = function (item)
    {
        verifyConnection(function () {
            openFlagModal(item);
        });
    };
```

I also plan to call the verifyConnection() function periodically as well. This solution seems to work and keep all the clients in sync with the server no matter what.  However, I don't like the fact that the SignalR client is *already* sending pings to the server, *and* re-establishing the connection, just not reconnecting the callback client methods. It makes me wonder if I'm doing something wrong to cause the client functions to not get reconnected.

Any thoughts on this solution?